# Source for not being a Shochet and Mohel

Tags: brit-milah, slaughter-shochet-shecht

I am looking for the source of a minhag that a shochet should not be a mohel because of an incident where the mohel/shochet recited "al hashechita" and the infant died afterwards. I recall that as an "eitza" to circumvent this problem, by giving a small pegima to the milah knife.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This custom couldn't have been popular in times of the *Amoraim* since it is brought (BT [Chullin 9a](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%98_%D7%90)):

> ואמר רב יהודה אמר רב
>   תלמיד חכם צריך שילמוד ג' דברים
>   כתב שחיטה ומילה

Trans. (Soncino):

> Rab Judah said in the name of Rab: A scholar must learn three things, viz.: writing,
>    shechitah, and circumcision.

R. [Yitzchak Lampronti](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Lampronti) (d. 1756) writes in his encyclopedia, Pachad Yitzchak (entry for "מוהל"; [p. 35a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20181&st=&pgnum=72)), that he had heard of this practice but did not know of any precedent. He quotes a responsum of a certain R. Netanel Saggri who alleged that the reason for this is because the hands of a ritual slaughter can tremble as he is accustomed to having the animal die in his hands and this reaction is dangerous when performing a circumcision. R. Lempronti rejects this reasoning and demonstrates that it is factually inaccurate. However, he records that he learned from incidents which were related to him, where a *shochet* performed a circumcision and accidentally pronounced the blessing ״...על השחיטה״ (instead of "על המילה") and the babe died, and as a precaution people would not have a shochet do a mohel's job.

A more kabbalistic [and pietistic-cautionary] standpoint is presented by [R. Chaim Elazar Shapiro](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Elazar_Spira), Grand rabbi of Munkatz, in his Os Chaim VeShalom ([269ff.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7764&st=&pgnum=277)) where he states, briefly put, that one who is a steady (permanent) *shochet* should not be a *mohel*. (He likewise interprets the aforementioned passage in Chullin as mere instruction for intermittent practice.)

Comment: Does _Chulin_ mean he should practice both or that he should know both?

Comment: @msh210 That's a fair q. When explaining the first two Rashi implies that they are to acquire the skill for practice; the third would presumably be so too.

Comment: Are the knives the same?

Comment: @DanF I'm frightened at the thought of a mohel pulling out a [knife used in livestock](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YjNdL_6Cebc) in order to perform a circumcision. No, it's most certainly not the same :)

Comment: @DanF (fundamentally any knife can be used for Milah, but practically you'd want something different)

Comment: I have to admit that I've never seen *shechita* done. (When I requested a case of chickens from the Empire plant, and realized that 2 rows of live chickens that I had seen when I first came to the plant, were suddenly gone, and the shochet calmly pointed to my box to tell me that that's were the chickens went, I became "ill" thinking about it.) So, I don't really know what their knife looks like. But wouldn't doing shechita on a chick (I don't know if anyone does that) suffice with a small knife?

Comment: Indeed a smaller knife is used for chicks (poultry in general too) and halachically it would be permissible to use for *milah* (S.Y. [YD §264:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.264.2?with=all&lang=bi)).